# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extractId' of undefined Ember Data while running QUnit tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, qunit

I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extractId' of undefined
```

while running integration tests with QUnit.

The failing test:

```
module "Points",
  setup: ->
    App.reset()
    Ember.run App, App.advanceReadiness

test "Index", ->
  visit("/points").then ->
    ok(exists(".title:contains('POINTS')"), "Retrieved title of points section")
    App.Point.find().then (points) ->
      equal(find(".listContainer li").length, points.get('length') , "Retrieved correct number of points")
```

Running this test in isolation works well but running this test within the module it throws the error mention above.
It seems like [`adapterForType(App.Point)`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1678) returns an undefined value.

Updating the test to

```
test "Index", ->
  result = App.Point.find()
  visit("/points").then ->
    ok(exists(".title:contains('POINTS')"), "Retrieved title of points section")
    result.then (points) ->
      equal(find(".listContainer li").length, points.get('length') , "Retrieved correct number of points")
```

mitigates the error.

The value retuned by `adapterForType` in the correct test is:

```
Ember.inspect(this.adapterForType(App.Point))
"{serializer: <DS.FixtureSerializer:ember455>, _attributesMap: [object Object], _configurationsMap: [object Object], _outstandingOperations: [object Object], _dependencies: [object Object]}"
```

Any suggestion related to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when running that test in isolation the adapter hasn't yet been created/initialized.  Or maybe it's lazy initialized the first time the adapter has been used.