# Ember integration test error

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, qunit, karma-runner

Based on [this excellent screencast](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/07/21/Integration-testing-your-emberjs-app-with-QUnit-and-Karma/) and [example](https://github.com/toranb/ember-testing-example), I've been able to unit test my Ember (RC7) app successfully, writing to model objects and such. I'm having trouble with integration testing. I even tried the most basic sort of test, as seen below, but to no avail. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

I'm getting this error from the console:

> LOG: 'App ready'
>
> INFO: 'generated -> route:application', Object{fullName: 'route:application'}
>
> LOG: 'NeedsAuthMixin: user not authenticated (1).'
>
> INFO: 'Rendering application with ', Object{fullName: 'view:application'}
>
> INFO: 'Rendering login with ', Object{fullName: 'view:login'}
>
> LOG: 'Transitioned into 'login''
>
> LOG: 'testing... login screen loads OK 1'
>
> LOG: 'Transitioned into 'login''
>
> Chrome 28.0.1500 (Mac OS X 10.6.8) Integration Tests - load login page FAILED
>       Expected 1 assertions, but 0 were run

Background: As you can see, as my app loads, it checks for user authentication, whereupon it transitions to a login page if user isn't authenticated.

This is the code that calls the test (generated from coffeescript):

```
asyncTest("test: load login page", function() {
  expect(1);
  console.log("testing... login screen loads OK 1");
  return visit("/login").then(function() {
    return ok(1 === 1, "Value equal 1.");
  });
});
```

My Karma config file is [here](https://gist.github.com/bkCDL/4eecea53011c95cf9f44).

Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work if you use `test()` instead of `asyncTest()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I just tried that, and I don't get the above error anymore (hooray!), but get this one instead, which I've seen before: **"...ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extractId' of undefined at /Users/.../Report3YO/app/components/ember/ember-data-latest.js:2627"** Does that error indicate that some object it's looking for is missing, or maybe hasn't been rendered when it was executed (thus, "undefined")?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without looking at it in debugger. `extractId` is a method that should be on the serializer. When test is running ember is trying to pass some model to the serializer's `extractId` function  but the serializer is undefined. Serializer is a property of your adapter and would be initialized when the app boots, so probably something wrong with the test setup. Sounds a lot like this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312596/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-extractid-of-undefined-ember-data-while

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback and the link to the other question. It took me awhile tinkering around, but I finally got it working. When I commented out all tests except the one above, it worked. Then I added one back and got the same "extractId" error. So on a lark, I commented out "App.reset();" in the module 'setup' function (see [test example link](https://github.com/toranb/ember-testing-example/blob/master/js/tests/integration_tests.js)), and both worked just fine. I had read that calling "reset" was required in testing in my setup with Karma-runner & QUnit, but I guess not anymore.